# ASP.NET Submit button doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form with `input type="submit"`. In the browser submit doesn't do anything. On the "network" tab in developer tools I see nothing. No errors in developer tools either.

My form looks like that:

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="section" id="msform">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ClubApplication", "Mining", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "app" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <fieldset>
                <div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Weiter" />
                <p style="color:#d7d7d7">* Pflichtfelder</p>
            </fieldset>
            @*
               More Fieldsets...
            *@
            <fieldset>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Intrests, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 materialize-textarea form-control", id = "textarea", rows = "4",  })
                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Zurück" />
                <input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Abschicken" />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </fieldset>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Server side (Not called in debug mode):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ClubApplication(ClubApplication application)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
      return View(application);

   return View(application); 
}
```

The full code is already live at CryptoWorld.Academy/Mining (you have to register to see the form).

It would be very nice if somebody got an idea why the form is just doing absolutely nothing when clicking the submit button.

Comment: Do you need an ajax form submit  ? If not , replace `Ajax.BeginForm` with `Html.BeginForm` and it's parameters. If you need the ajax behavior, check your browser console to see any possible script errors which is causing the issue.

Comment: @Shyju I don't really need it but also the Html.BeginForm (standard html form) is not working. I had it before using ajax and thought ajax may work. But both dont.

Comment: @Shyju There are also no errors in the console

Answer (score 0):

When your using "Ajax.BeginForm()" then the form will be submitted using JavaScript. you need change "_Layout.cshtml" in shared view, so add the JavaScript file "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" reference on it to handle the ajax form submission request on post-back.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I added now the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax to the _Layout but it is still not working. I had the same issue before I switched to ajax with the standard post form.

Comment: check in browser console any error is showing or not ?. resolve that issue..if any.

Comment: As I wrote in the question there are no errors in the console. I mean if you register (just mail and pw) at CryptoWorld.Academy/Mining you can see the from that is not submitting

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by the form data you are sending to the POST method not matching the object you are expecting as a parameter.

Try opening developer tools (I prefer to use Chrome) and checking in the network tab what is being posted. Click on the method name in the network window and scroll down to view the form data.

This should match your model exactly, including any non-nullable properties.